# Compute $a\otimes a$ in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis, cylindrical-coordinates

I want to compute $a\otimes a$ if $a\in \mathbb{R}^3$ is given in cylindrical coordinates, i.e. $a=a_{\rho}e_{\rho}+a_{\varphi}e_{\varphi}+a_z e_z$, where $e_{\rho}=(\cos(\varphi),\sin(\varphi),0),e_{\varphi}=(-\sin(\varphi),\cos(\varphi),0),e_z=(0,0,1)$.

**My first attempt:**
$a\otimes a$ is independent of the basis, i.e.
\begin{align}
a\otimes a = \begin{pmatrix}a_{\rho}^2 & a_{\rho}a_{\varphi} & a_{\rho}a_z \\\\
a_{\rho}a_{\varphi} & a_{\varphi}^2 & a_{z}a_{\varphi}\\\\
a_{z}a_{\rho}& a_{z}a_{\varphi} & a_z^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
**But**
if we repeat this with the euclidean basis we get
\begin{align}
a\otimes a = \begin{pmatrix}a_{x}^2 & a_{x}a_{y} & a_{y}a_z \\\\
a_{x}a_{y} & a_{y}^2 & a_{z}a_{y}\\\\
a_{z}a_{x}& a_{z}a_{y} & a_z^2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
If we compare these matrices it must hold $a_x^2=a_{\rho}^2$ which is wrong in general. By change of coordinates we know that for $e_x=(1,0,0), e_y=(0,1,0), e_z=(0,0,1)$
\begin{align}
&a_x=a\cdot e_x = (a_{\rho}e_{\rho}+a_{\varphi}e_{\varphi}+a_z e_z)e_x= a_{\rho}\cos(\varphi)-a_{\varphi}\sin(\varphi)\\\\
&a_y=a\cdot e_y = (a_{\rho}e_{\rho}+a_{\varphi}e_{\varphi}+a_z e_z)e_y= a_{\rho}\sin(\varphi)+a_{\varphi}\cos(\varphi)\\\\
&a_z=a_z
\end{align}
If we plug these in into $a\otimes a$ we should get the right matrix.

**Question**
What is wrong with my first attempt? It seems that $a\otimes a$ is not independent of the basis, am I at least right in this point?

Comment: If you apply the same logic of the first attempt to $a$ (a 1st rank tensor) you will probably wrongly conclude that $a_x=a_\rho,a_y=a_\varphi\,.$ Hint: vectors and tensors transform under changes of coordinate systems. In other words: those matrices need not agree.

Comment: Can you specify which matrices you mean? Is what I did in the second step wrong?

Comment: The very same matrices you displayed in OP. The 2nd step is only half baked. I have no appetite to complete this for you. Please try it yourself.

Comment: Or let me rephrase: if you step back to consider $a$ in Cartesian vs cylindrical coordinates. Which one is the "right" one? Answer: both. Do the ***components*** $a_x,a_y$ have to agree with $a_\rho,a_\varphi$ ? Answer: NO. The same logic applies to $a\otimes a$. The matrices are both right but do not have to agree.

Comment: The confusion is probably more of a conceptual thing that you could fix with better notation. Start to distinguish a vector/tensor (which is a priori an object that does not need components or a basis) from its representation in a coordinate system.

Comment: @KurtG. if I understand correctly I can work with both of the matrices and there are two changing matrices $C_1,C_2$ so that $A_1=C_1 A_2 C_2$ where $A_1$ denotes the matrix from my first attempt and $A_2$ the second matrix where I used euclidean coordinates?

Comment: Yes. This sounds about right. 2nd rank tensors transform in exactly that way.

Comment: @KurtG. thanks for your help and advice! I think the problem was lying in that what you said. I was thinking in coordinates and not much in "objects"

Comment: The components of the two matrices you have shown are with respect to *two different bases*, and hence cannot be compared. It is no wonder that they are not equal. (Edit: "matrix" is a poor choice of word, because they are $(2,0)$ tensors.